# Android kills service after day is over?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, realm, sensors

I've got a little problem here, I quite don't know how to solve.

I'm using a simple Service which registers a StepDetector (not Counter as I want to take care of Steps myself). It is started Sticky.

Also, I implemented a BroadcastReceiver. It listens for BOOT_Completed and Service_Destroyed. As far as I can tell, it is working great, when rebooting or force-quitting the app. It keeps on counting and storing Data in the Realm-Database.

To explain a bit further: I store the Step-Data in two tables.

1. Stores them on a perHour-Basis, meaning that every step taken is written to the corespodonding Hour-Row.
   Example:
   Hour 5 - 60 Steps taken
   Hour 7 - 30 Steps taken
2. Stores them on a perDay-Basis. Here all steps taken on that day are stored.

My onStartCommand looks like that:

```
    manager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    stepDetectorSensor = manager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
    manager.registerListener(this, stepDetectorSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    return Service.START_STICKY;
```

This is my onSensorChanged

```
 if(stamp == 0){
        stamp = event.timestamp;
    }
    if(stamp != event.timestamp) {

        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);

        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                Date date = new Date();

                DailyValues dailyValues = realm.where(DailyValues.class).equalTo("type", DailyValues.STEPS).findAll()
                        .where().equalTo("Day", date.getDay()).findAll()
                        .where().equalTo("Month", date.getMonth()).findAll()
                        .where().equalTo("Year", date.getYear()).findFirst();


                ValuesPerHour valuesPerHour = realm.where(ValuesPerHour.class).equalTo("type", ValuesPerHour.STEPS).findAll()
                        .where().equalTo("hour", date.getHours()).findAll()
                        .where().equalTo("day", date.getDay()).findFirst();

                if (dailyValues != null) {
                    dailyValues.Value += 1;
                } else {
                    RealmResults<ValuesPerHour> row = realm
                            .where(ValuesPerHour.class).equalTo("type", ValuesPerHour.STEPS).findAll()
                            .where().notEqualTo("day",date.getDay()).findAll();
                    row.deleteAllFromRealm();
                    dailyValues = realm.createObject(DailyValues.class);
                    dailyValues.Day = date.getDay();
                    dailyValues.Month = date.getMonth();
                    dailyValues.Year = date.getYear();
                    dailyValues.Value = 1;
                    dailyValues.type = dailyValues.STEPS;

                }

                if (valuesPerHour != null)
                    valuesPerHour.value += 1;
                else {
                    valuesPerHour = realm.createObject(ValuesPerHour.class);
                    valuesPerHour.value = 1;
                    valuesPerHour.hour = date.getHours();
                    valuesPerHour.day = date.getDay();
                    valuesPerHour.type = valuesPerHour.STEPS;
                }


            }
        });
        stamp = event.timestamp;
    }
```

It is not the final version so there might be some design faults but as you can see, I look if there is already Data for "Today" determined by Day Month and year. If there is, add a step. If not, add a row, add a step to it and clear perHour-Table.
Then I do almost the same with the perHour-Table to update it.

My onDestroy()

```
super.onDestroy();
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(".RestartSensor");
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Simply sends the Restart stuff.
And last but not least, the Receivers onReceive-Methode:

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, StepCounterService.class));
        Log.i("Restart", "Restarted");
```

Manifest is also good, as I get step counts on Force-Close and Restart of Phone.
The only thing that is making me nuts is, that when a new day is there, and I start moving the phone without starting the app first, no steps are registered.
Only after starting the app everything works fine again.

Edit: Right ATM I use startForeground to avoid this issue. But Apps like
sHealth get this done without any sticky Notification. So basically I would like to know how to get a Service restarted, no matter what happens.

As mentioned in the comments, onDestroy won't get called always, so a restart is not guaranteed.
Another issue might be that Android puts the app in doze (?) so maybe I need a Wakelock?

I don't think it is about the read/write methode as it works on any other situation.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that onDestroy will be called when a service is killed

Comment: so how can I fix this?

Comment: I dont have time or motivation to dig into your case. Just giving some information

Comment: use AlarmManager to start service i faced same problem in a project and do the same.

Comment: Problem is: I want the service to run even without activity around. On Reboot or closing the App the step counter should count on without any delay. How can the AlarmManager start the service without Activity on Service-Death? I think it could be the doze mode or anything. Maybe it is how I treat the RealmDatabase. But then, when I start the app shortly it is counting perfectly again. As I said: It works good for the most time (Reboot and shut down of App). But after some point it just dies.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I've got it working now.
I hope someone will comment if there is something wrong or bad practice.
Please, if you see anything, help me fixing it. 
Also, I need to know if this approach drains too heavy on the battery.

My approach has two mechanisms working in the receiver.

1. Using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver and using startWakefulService.
2. Set AlarmManager in onReceive() to call onReceive every 5 Seconds

This is my onReceive()-Methode:

```
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intentReciever = new Intent(context, SensorRestartBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentReciever, 0);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*1000,
            5*1000, alarmIntent);


    if(isServiceRunning(context,StepCounterService.class) == false){
        sMonitorServiceIntent = new Intent(context, StepCounterService.class);
        startWakefulService(context,sMonitorServiceIntent);
        Log.i("BroadcastReceiver", "Restarted");
    }
    else{
        Log.i("BroadcastReceiver", "Is running");
    }
```

As you see, isServiceRunning is called which looks like that:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo serviceInfo : am
            .getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        String className1 = serviceInfo.service.getClassName();
        String className2 = serviceClass.getName();
        if (className1.equals(className2)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

It simply checks if an Instance of this Service is already running.
If not, restart the service, else nothing is to be done.

Problem is: 
ATM I start the Service via the MainActivity and saving an instance.
That way I can call Service.Stop to initiate the onDestroy in the Service.

When I start the service via Broadcast which gets called by the activity
I cannot call Service.Stop which leads the service not to recreate itself.
I tried it. Using Activity -> Broadcast -> Service results in no Counts if the Service or App gets killed.

My current approach is to check in MainActivity is Service is running. If not, run it. Service calls the initial call to the Receiver in onStartCommand() to ensure the Receiver starts running.